# Network analysis in R: error using findGraph function in qgraph package

Tags: r

I can't get the findGraph function in the qgraph package to work.

The code I'm using is:

```
optGraph <- findGraph(dataCors, nrow(data), type = "pcor")
optimalGraph <- qgraph(optGraph, layout = corGraph$layout,
                       groups = Groups, legend.cex = 0.3, 
                       cut = 0.1, maximum = 1, minimum = 0, esize = 20,
                       vsize = 5)
```

With the output:

> Error in findGraph(dataCors, nrow(data), type = "pcor") : could not find function "findGraph"

I have downloaded all the recommended packages.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a supported function in the *qgraph* package. I recommend that you use the `ggmModSelect` instead of `findGraph`, which is a superior method of aiming to achieve the same result. See also this publication:

https://psycnet.apa.org/doiLanding?doi=10.1037%2Fmet0000439